# Upgrade is not working due to dpkg being used by another process

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, python3, unattended-upgrades

I am unable to install anything on my Ubuntu 20.04. The reason looks like  **dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process**. This is used by following root process  **/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade**. Also I tried to kill the process but I am getting following error:**bash: kill: (9006) - Operation not permitted**.Not sure what I can do.Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: This is normal *if* it finishes after a while, and releases the lock. So try again after a few minutes, and come back, if the lock stays for a long time. If possible to reboot, you can try that too, but it should not be necessary.

Comment: Let Unattended Upgrades complete first, and then you'll be able to do upgrades.

Comment: Hi @sudodus ,Thank you for the response. Actually it has been there for around a week now so I am not sure what can be done.

Comment: What happens after reboot?

Comment: Hi @heynnema Thank you for the response. The process has been there for around a week. So can you suggest what can I do so the process gets complete.

Comment: @sudodus reboot as in restart right? if yes then nothing changes even after reboot.

Comment: I see. Well, I suggest that you try according to the listed commands that I have picked up at the Ubuntu Forums (Oldfred's command list).

Comment: Sure Thank you I will go through it and will post here which one worked for me.

Comment: It is possible that none of them works because of the lock. Then some more advanced/risky method must be used. Anyway, while you can run the system, please backup everything that you cannot afford to lose (documents, pictures ...).

Comment: This like of lockfile error typically occurs due to an unclean shutdown/poweroff. Did that happen to you?

Comment: Maybe the "Remove lock" section can help you. And after that you may have to run several of the other commands to repair the database of the current versions of the program packages.

Comment: @sudodus Your answer won't remove the `lock-frontend` file.

Comment: @Pranav When you tried to kill the process, did you use `sudo`?

Comment: @heynnema, I guess and hope that after a few questions and answers, you will suggest a working method.

Answer (score 0):

#### Oldfred's command list for cleaning and repairing

```
#houseclean
sudo apt-get autoclean # only removes files that cannot be downloaded anymore (obsolete)
sudo apt-get clean

#refresh
sudo apt-get update #resync package index
sudo apt-get upgrade #newest versions of all packages, update must be run first

#would upgrade you to the latest kernel in the repositories
#dist-upgrade is also able to remove existing packages if required
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

# fix Broken packages -f 
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a

# Remove lock
# If you are absolutely sure you do not have another upgrade process running.
# Locked dpkg - only if sure you are not running another update.

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a 

# added zika's tip for problems with hash sum mismatch

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update

# added 2F4U's tips for Package Manager & Update Manager problems
#Does executing these commands help?

cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
# This will rebuild the cache.
```

If none of these commands helps, this Ubuntu Forums thread has additional suggestions:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869890